# Object serialization query and class path

Tags: java, serialization, classpath

I had a question in regards to serializing an object and being able to retrieve the object in a different program. The problem with retrieving an object in a different program is that the program cant find the object(symbol). 
From what I understand this serialized object needs to be on a classpath.

(Still a student and not sure exactly what it means to place an object on a class path)

My question is how do you place an object on a classpath using NetBeans 7.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should have the serialized Java Class exported as a JAR file. The consuming App, the one which deserializes it, should have this jar on its class path in order to deserialize it... Btw, you are de/serializing an Object i.e. a Class Instance, not the class itself.

[Netbeans project-classpath](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath)